# Luke 23:43: “I say to you today, you will be with me in paradise” or “I say to you, today you will be with me in paradise”?

Tags: luke, punctuation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Comma? “Verily I say unto thee to day, …” or “Verily I say unto thee, to day…”](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/897/comma-verily-i-say-unto-thee-to-day-or-verily-i-say-unto-thee-to-day)

Luke 23:43: “I say to you today, you will be with me in paradise” or “I say to you, today you will be with me in paradise”?

I've heard that in the original language there is no punctuation, so we can place comma either before or after "today". Is this possible to give a hermeneutic analyze of this matter?

The second option looks kind of more logical to me at the moment (otherwise, what was the point for Jesus to specify that He was speaking those words to the thief exactly on that very day that He was speaking to him - was that not self-obvious in the first place?), but I may be not seeing some important points here.